# Interpolating values for NaN pixels using ENVI?

Tags: raster, interpolation, imagery, envi

I'm currently using MODIS data and am running into problems with NaN values in the final product caused by clouds.  I'm interesting in a simple way to spatially interpolate (fill in) these NaN values.

Is there a menu function (in ENVI) that can easily/simply do this without delving into the intricacies IDL?

Comment: Can you please describe a little more what is your final goal? Is it just for rendering purpose or for data analysis? In the later case especially it might be better to fill the blank pixel using different shot of the area over a period of time rather than to interpolate. However I'm by far not an expert in raster imagery.

Comment: Not so much for data analysis but really for aesthetics/presentation.  I'm creating a multitemporal stack (time series) of apparent thermal inertia plots derived from MODIS and I need them to look consistent as much as possible (i.e. no holes in the data).

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange! (forgot all politeness earlier, sorry!). You can edit your question directly. By doing so you can use nice formating and/or join snapshot to help potential answerers easily figure out your issue. In the comment section important informations might be less visible. Unfortunately I'm not a regular ENVI user so I can only help you get more visibility by improving your post.